# MySQL join table that returns multiple rows as one result, SUM()med up?

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many, sum, rows

I'm facing a problem here: when running the following query I only get one row back even though it should return "every player found in a pickup, his nickname, the team he played on, his ID and the total amount of kills he committed during a pickup (match)"

```
SELECT alias.name alias, team.name team, sid.steam_id steam_id, 
      SUM(kills) kills_total 
FROM pickup
    JOIN player ON player.pickup_id = pickup.id
    JOIN team ON player.team_id = team.id
    JOIN sid ON player.sid_id = sid.id
    JOIN alias ON player.alias_id = alias.id
    JOIN weapon_stats_1 ws1 ON ws1.pickup_id = pickup.id AND ws1.player_id = player.id
WHERE pickup.logfile_name = 'logfilename'
```

The **weapon_stats_1** table looks: [image: table]

To illustrate it more readable it could be seen like:

```
pickup_id     player_id    weapon_id    kills    teamkills
logfilename1  0:0:1        Shotgun      12       2
logfilename1  0:0:1        RPG          19       0
logfilename1  0:0:2        Grenade      5        8
```

What I want to do is grabbing the total amount of **kills** by summing  it up using **SUM()** and add it as resulting column to the query above. For this example it should return something similiar to:

```
alias        team   steam_id    kills_total
nickname1    Red    0:0:1       31
nickname2    Blue   0:0:2       5
```

When I remove the ***JOIN weapon[...]*** line the query returns exactly what I want it to - in this specific case for **pickup.logfile_name = 'logfilename'** that looks like:

[image: result]

I do not understand what I am doing wrong and why the query only returns *ONE* row (one player) when I **JOIN weapon_stats_1 ws1 [...]**. How do I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Regards

Comment: Thank you very much, if I only had known this 3 hours ago. Works like a charm now, just appending ` GROUP BY player.id, pickup.id` and it returns everything like I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT alias.name alias, team.name team, sid.steam_id steam_id, 
      SUM(kills) kills_total 
FROM pickup
    JOIN player ON player.pickup_id = pickup.id
    JOIN team ON player.team_id = team.id
    JOIN sid ON player.sid_id = sid.id
    JOIN alias ON player.alias_id = alias.id
    LEFT JOIN weapon_stats_1 ws1 ON ws1.pickup_id = pickup.id AND ws1.player_id = player.id
WHERE pickup.logfile_name = 'logfilename' GROUP BY player.id, pickup.id
```

credits to @otzy